# Sharepoint api search by properties

Tags: api

I am trying to see if I am able to search sharepoint from a given string

```
https://myShrp_URL/My%20Document/_api/search/query?querytext='Node: 592832'&selectproperties='Node'
```

I notice it is not finding such node because it is under a subfolder?
Is there a way to make selectproperties a global search so it doesnt have to document library specific or subfolder specific?

The directory was like this

/My%20Document/Doc/level_A.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I'm clear on your question...

- Unless you supply a path restriction, the search is global.
- Your query `querytext='Node: 592832'` works IF "Node" is a Managed Property. (Has this been configured as a search Managed Property?)
- SelectProperties is list of Managed Properties to return in the search results and should not impact your filtering.